# Getting Runtime Error 3141 in MS Access when try and run SQL SELECT query needed for a string for an array

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a calendar in MS Access and am adapting a calendar template I have found online. I have created a SELECT statement to populate the Openrecordset string used for the array but keep getting the run-time error 3141.

Unfortunately the previous dba created a field in one of the tables called tblAttendanceRecord.Date and I am not sure if it is this that is causing the problem or whether there is other obvious errors in the code.

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblAttendanceRecord.PayrollNo, tblAttendanceRecord.[Date] AS [ADate], " & _
         "tblAttendanceTypes.[Attendance Name] AS AttendName, tblAttendanceTypes.Code, " & _
         "FROM tblAttendanceRecord INNER JOIN tblAttendanceTypes ON tblAttendanceRecord.TypeID = tblAttendanceTypes.ID " & _
         "WHERE tblAttendanceRecord.PayrollNo = #" & intID & "# " & _
         "ORDER BY [ADate];"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then............
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To me, I think it's the `Order By` clause... try `Order By tblAttendanceRecord.[Date]` instead of the alias column. I might be wrong though...

Comment: Thank you. I have tried changing that and still get the error unfortunately. Very frustrating.

Comment: You need to remove the comma after `tblAttendanceTypes.Code,`

Comment: @TMcKeown, good catch!

Answer (score 2):

***Error 3141 in MS Access means an error in the `SELECT`***

You have an extra comma BEFORE THE `FROM`

```
tblAttendanceTypes.Code, <-- that comma is your problem.
```

Comment: Thanks always good to have another set of eyes look over it. I will try if that and removing ORDER BY stops the error.